# Woocommerce Checkout page modify login-cart-and coupon code?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, checkout, cart

I am trying to edit my Woocommerce checkout page, and I have this few questions:

1. The login bar is shown only the first time you try to checkout. It disappears after you refresh the page or the next time you try to checkout.
2. The login link is not working. If you click on the " Cliquez Ici Pour Vous Connecter" (click here to reconnect) nothing happens.
3. I want to hide the "check my cart section" is that possible?
4. Can I put the coupon code section before the paypal section?

This is my website: http://www.reussirlegmat.com/check-out-test/

Comment: Thank you dear :) I did contact the support and will be waiting for their replies.

Comment: Loic, Can I ask u a question? are u available?